# What is the glibc GLRO macro?

Tags: c, glibc

I'm currently trying to understand how the glibc startup routines (__libc_start_main) process Elf Auxiliary vector types (auxv_t).

Browsing through the source code for glibc, I find references to some function named GLRO. In trying to track down the definition for this function, the closest I can find is

```
#define GLRO(x) _##x
```

When I search for "*##x", all I find is other similar "#define" directives, which leaves me confused. What does this definition mean? Is "*##x" some kind of compiler directive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a preprocessor macro.

You can see for yourself what it does by running the preprocessor. Just make a sample file, like this:

```
// foo.c
#include <some_glibc_header.h>

GLRO(hello)
```

Now run the preprocessor:

```
gcc -E foo.c
```

You'll see that the macro creates a new token by putting an underscore in front of the given token; in our example we obtain `_hello`. The `##` preprocessor operator concatenates tokens.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 9):

Kerrek SB's answer provides what it does, but not the macro's *purpose*.  So here it is:

"The GLRO() macro is used to access global or local read-only data, see sysdeps/generic/ldsodefs.h."

Source: http://cygwin.com/ml/libc-help/2012-03/msg00006.html

Answer (score 3):

```
#define GLRO(x) _##x
```

`##` is the token pasting operator and it concatenates its two operands.

e.g., `a ## b` yields `ab` and `_ ## x` yields `_x`.

So for example:

```
GLRO(my_symbol) = 0;
```

would result in:

```
_my_symbol = 0;
```